# How to change div's style according to divs inside?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've got a `div` in which people can import photos (like cover). While they haven't uploaded any photos it has a cover image, but when they upload photo in it background changes to white. (That's how I want to work, but it's not working)

This example is working :

```js
   $(document).ready(function () {
                if ('#bgbg:not(:empty)') {
                    $('#bgbg').css({ 'background-color':'#fff',
                        'background-image':'none !important' });

                }
            });
```

```css
.profile-photo-bg {
    background-image:url("../images/cover-placeholder.jpg");
    background-size:cover;

    height:245px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div  class="profile-photo-bg no-padding col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div id="bgbg" class="profile-photo-bg2">

                    <div ng-repeat="image in theUser.attributes.ImageGallery " class=" galleryImage2 " style="background:url({{image._url}}) 50% 50% / cover; ">
                        <i class='ion-close' ng-click='deleteFromGallery(image)'></i></div>

                    </div>

                </div>
```

Now I have different code with `a` inside which is not working with the same jquery script:

```html
<div  id="bgbg3" class="profile-photo-bg no-padding col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                   <a style="" class="fotki" ng-repeat="image in theUser.attributes.ImageGallery" href="{{image._url}}" data-lightbox="gallery">
                       <div ng-if='$index < 5' class="galleryImage2 " style="background-image:url({{image._url}}); background-size: cover; "></div>
                   </a>
               </div>
```

I use angularjs, jquery, ionic.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your JavaScript syntax. You should be selecting the element like `$('#bgbg')` in your `if` statement. Also, you should be checking if the div has children inside your `if` statement instead of using a selector. Adding a class to your div is also better than having pure css applied with jQuery.

The JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.bgbg').each(function() {
        if ($(this).children().length == 0) {
            $(this).addClass('no-children');
        }
    })
});
```

The CSS:

```
.bgbg {
    background-image:url("http://www.gigcity.ca/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Tool-feature.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
    height:245px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.bgbg.no-children {
    background-image: none !important;
    background-color: white;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div  class="profile-photo-bg no-padding col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
  <div class="profile-photo-bg2 bgbg">
    <div ng-repeat="image in theUser.attributes.ImageGallery " class=" galleryImage2 " style="background:url({{image._url}}) 50% 50% / cover; ">
      <i class='ion-close' ng-click='deleteFromGallery(image)'></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="profile-photo-bg no-padding col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
  <div class="profile-photo-bg2 bgbg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/108ws2c6/

Comment: only this changed :     background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); , i need that my background-image would be none;

Comment: I've edited the answer & added an example. Take a look.

Comment: With this one I've got no problem, I have problems with a inside <a> div.

Comment: And no it's not working for some reason, it shows both with bg.